# "Page cannot be displayed" error shows when i try to call an object of a class in my jar folder on jsp

Tags: jsp

I have the below code snippet in my JSP which doesn't give the page error,

```
//Newly added Code
<%@page import= "phide.*"%>
<% 
    randomString rand; // = new randomString();
    String pass = "lone";//=rand.randomString();
    String sUserID = "User1";
    String [] userInfo = {pass,sUserID};
    achieve executer; //= new achieve();
    /*try {
       String [] userDtls = executer.achieve(userInfo);
    } catch(Exception e)
    { }*/
%> 

//End of newly added Code
```

but once I remove the comment line"//" the error "Page cannot be displayed" comes up...Please would appreciate it so much in getting any idea on how to solve this

Comment: How did you embed your java code in the jsp file?

Comment: Thank you..<%@ page import="phide.*,com.infy.bbu.sso.admin.*%>

Comment: the phide.jar is the jar file that contains the classes am trying to use..

Comment: <%@page import= "phide.*"%>    <%  
     String   sUserID = "TES11";
    randomString rand = new randomString();
    String pass =rand.randomString();

    String [] userInfo = {pass,sUserID}; 

    achieve executer = new achieve();
try {
    String [] userDtls = executer.achieve(userInfo);
}catch(Exception e){
    
}
%>

Comment: I assume the imports are missing and you call the classes wrong. Class names must be start with a capaitalized letter. Replace `new randomString();`by `new RandomString();` etc.